# How does I get image store in folder using path Store in sql

Tags: c#

I am storing path of image upload to a folder in db as

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Audio/" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
string anspath1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Audio/"),FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileNam);
if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
     an.Ans_Image = anspath1;
     an.Question_Table_Id = Q_last.Id;
     an.Value = true;
     ef.AnswerTables.Add(an);
     ef.SaveChanges();
}
```

i want to get this image on aspx page using Image1.Url method how can i Get it

Comment: Are you able to get the path from DB ?

Comment: yes,here is the code  var last = (from ls in ef.AnswerTables select ls).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            string filepath = last.Ans_Image;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string filepath= "~/" +filepath.Substring(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.Length).Replace("\\", "/");
Image1.ImageUrl = filepath;
```